# How does the circuit depth of a bijective function change if it is optimally rexpressed in terms of larger gates?

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits, reversible-computing

Consider a bijective function $f:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$. Let $d_k$ be the minimal circuit depth of $f$ when expressed in terms of arbitrary $k$ bit gates (i.e. arbitrary bijective functions on $\{0,1\}^k$). Suppose $d_k$ is known for $k=k_0$. Are there known bounds on $d_k$ in terms of $k$ and $d_{k_0}$?

The unusual definition of gates here is motivated by the way they are used in quantum computing. There gates correspond to unitary operations, which necessarily have the same sized input and output.

Comment: What does "optimally" means, here? Minimal depth of all possible circuits?

Comment: Usually a $k$-bit "gate" is not a bijective function on $\{0,1\}^k$, but rather an arbitrary function $\{0,1\}^k \to \{0,1\}$.  Do you have something unusual in mind?  Can you [edit] your question accordingly?  Also please don't leave clarifications in the comments: instead, [edit] your question (e.g., to include a definition of what "optimally") means.